# Unix - Piping each file in a directory to a program one at a time

Tags: bash, unix

I have a directory of input files, each of which I am running cat on and piping to STDIN of a ruby program file, like so:

```
cat Laser-Maze-with-Mirrors_testcases/input005.txt | ruby laser-maze.rb
```

I have a feeling this is simple, but how do I pipe the cat of these files in one at a time? Right now I'm typing each one manually, which seems like a really dumb thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the files. Note that redirection is probably a bit more direct than `cat` in this case, and that you should always quote the arguments in a case like this in case there happen to be spaces in the files.

```
for f in Laser-Maze-with-Mirrors_testcases/*.txt; do
    ruby laser-maze.rb < "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as

```
for file in /mypath/*
do
    cat $file | ruby laser-maze.rb
done
```

should work in a shell script

Answer (score 1):

`find /mypath -type f -exec ruby laser-made.rb < {} \;` will also work

Comment: Except it will create a process, which the other answers will not